# Which water is easier to filter? Rain water or tap water

Tags: everyday-chemistry, bond, water, filtering

I understand the water greatly varies depending on the region and filtration differs as well. Is it better to filter rain water or tap water from contamination like hormones, pesticides, and cloud seeding, which are hard to filter? Is there a better place/SE to ask this?

Comment: Why do you need to filter hormones out of rainwater?

Comment: Ordinary filtration cannot remove dissolved impurities.

Comment: If you fear hormones in rainwater, then you have a problem indeed, and not one that can be solved at Chem.SE.

Comment: @IvanNeretin there is a certain level of hormones in all tap water from agriculture and birth control and maybe rain water but it is not the limiting factor. Which water is easier to filter?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun, There are hundreds of other compounds in water too. It all depends on what levels are you looking at. More and more sensitive machines can detect a few molecules. I feel that you have misread or watched some pseudoscience videos. Yes, there are human hormones in waste water along with all types of junk that one can imagine, but that does not mean that tap will contain all that. The way Nature has been designed, it takes care of all those things. Bacteria, sunlight, oxygen all work for you in Nature!

Comment: Why would a hormone in rainwater? Too fresh?

Comment: "I understand the water greatly varies depending on the region and filtration differs as well. " Then maybe you'd care to be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: All surface water and high ground water started out as evaporated ocean water that condensed on a nanoparticle, scrubbed the air as the droplet formed and fell, landed, extracted whatever it flowed on, eventually collected in streams, ponds, lakes, rivers temporarily, picking up ions, biomass, possibly suspended solids and exchanging gases on its way back to the Oceans. This IGNORES industrial pollution that can be pervasive [Remember how everything cleared up in the start of the pandemic].

Each phase has its own purification problems. First step is an analysis. The least complicated is rainwater collected and settled; then new surface water, Municipal sources [tap water] usually have some pretreatment and usually supply an analysis; then high-level ground water such as springs, then shallow wells, deeper wells; Finally sinks such as the Dead Sea, the Great Salt Lake, the ocean, and sewage [space station].

A rain water story: I taught high school chemistry for 2 years at a school 2 blocks from Kodak Park, Eastman Kodak's industrial complex. While in class a sudden thunderstorm caused a deluge and everyone said, "Let's check it for acid rain".  A girl sitting next to the window held out a bucket to collect water; after several seconds she screamed and pulled her arm in! There were black tendrils hanging all over it. We quickly wiped it off and got her to the girl's room to wash her arm and to the nurse to get checked out, no irritation. We never checked for acid rain or had the substance analysed.

Comment: What was the substance? Something from the roof?

Answer (score -1):

You provided incomplete detail (region you live on, what the quality of your tap water is and it origins from, and if cloud seeding is really relevant on your area, or if there are other industrial sources that emit particles and aerosol nearby) to get more than a generic answer.

In Germany for instance the answer would be different as in the USA or in agricultural regions with heavy pestcide use elseshere.

Using ultra-filtration membrane combined with activated carbon filters often is good enough, and proven to improve typical tap water. If you have a problem with heavy metals a little more effort is needed.

Q: rain or tap water easier to filter?
A: it depends, see above

Q: which contaminants are more complicated to get rid of by filtering?
A: nanoparticles, nitrates, heavy metals,...

Comment: I just wanted to know overall is it easier or better to filter tap water over rain or snow even. +1 thanks for answering

Comment: BTW: why was I downvoted? I want to learn ;)